# How to remove a circular dependency as pointed out in a libgdx tutorial

Tags: game-design

In [this libgdx tutorial](http://steigert.blogspot.se/2012/02/2-libgdx-tutorial-game-screens.html), the author says he's not happy with the circular dependency between the game and the screens.

How can this diagram:

[image]

be improved to remove that dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. **Game** class is the one that handles the **Screens**, and the Screens need to be able to communicate with it to tell it which Screen it should set next.

That dependency isn't really a big of a deal. Just having a reference to the Game in your Screens (via the abstract Screen that all of them extends from).

If you want to change that, you would need to create your own **Game** and **Screen** classes, with a different design. (Not worth the effort if you ask me)

Comment: OK, so there's no real problems using this model for developing a proper game?

Comment: Nop. Just have the Game reference and use it to go from Screen to Screen. (game.setScreen(new SettingsScreen) for example) Nothing wrong with it.